# Align section numbers and title

Tags: vertical-alignment

If I have:

```
\documentclass{report} %use KOMA scrbook
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Für Umlaute
\usepackage{helvet}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{multicol} % mehrere Spalten

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{varwidth} 
\usepackage{linegoal} 

\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{10pt}{0}\bfseries}{}{0em}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner ysep=1.75mm,text width=85mm,
    align=left,left color=black!15,right color=black!15] 
    {\thesection\hspace{5mm}\parbox[t][0pt][t]{\linewidth}{\raggedright #1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2} 
\section{aaaa}
\section{bbbb}
\section{cccc}
\section{dddd}
\section{eeee}
\section{ffff}
\section{gggg}
\section{hhhh}
\section{iiii}
\section{jjjj}
\section{kkkk}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

The section number should **all** end at the first red line and **all** section titles should begin at the second red line.

How can I force this?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my solution? That is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: @TeXnician No, this is absolutely perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a corrected version of that code. Just enclose `\thesection` with `\parbox`. That you can adjust to your needs.

```
\documentclass{report} %use KOMA scrbook
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Für Umlaute
\usepackage{helvet}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{multicol} % mehrere Spalten

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{varwidth} 
\usepackage{linegoal} 

\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{10pt}{0}\bfseries}{}{0em}
  {%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner ysep=1.75mm,text width=85mm,
    align=left,left color=black!15,right color=black!15] 
    {\parbox{10mm}{\raggedleft\thesection}\hspace{5mm}\parbox[t][0pt][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-15mm}{\raggedright #1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2} 
\section{Short title}
\section{bbbb}
\section{cccc}
\section{dddd}
\section{eeee}
\section{ffff}
\section{A longer title}
\section{hhhh}
\section{iiii}
\section{jjjj}
\section{kkkk}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```